# gulp serve command not working on SPFX using react

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I am getting following error while running `gulp serve` command.

I am working on the SPFX using react while running the project getting this error for the task.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of node are you using

Comment: I am using Node version 8.11.4 as SPFX not supported to above versions of the node.

Comment: According to errors on the screen you have some bugs in a code, you can dpeloy your solution to a git and let others quickly open it on own env briefly check wht is wrong :)